# Accessing GDI drawing context pixels directly

Tags: winapi, buffer, gdi

I want to read and write pixels directly from/to a drawing context, i.e. during a paint operation on a window.

I understand that there are `GetPixel`/`SetPixel` functions in Windows GDI, but for big operations it would be far better to be able to read and write pixel data directly to memory.

How can I do this using standard GDI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a compatible DC, Bitmap:

```
HDC     hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HBITMAP hBmp   = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
SelectObject(hMemDC, hBmp);
```

Next, there is [GetDIBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function you can use to get bits:

```
int GetDIBits(
  _In_     HDC hdc,
  _In_     HBITMAP hbmp,
  _In_     UINT uStartScan,
  _In_     UINT cScanLines,
  _Out_    LPVOID lpvBits,
  _Inout_  LPBITMAPINFO lpbi,
  _In_     UINT uUsage
);
```

**NOTE:** You might need to set lpvBits to NULL to get the dimensions and format of the image via BITMAPINFO (lpbi parameter).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GetObject` to get the `BITMAP` struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932477.aspx) which contains a pointer to the bitmap's data.